# setFormulas to a new spreadsheets when created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

I have been searching through question and example everywhere but I can not seem to find an answer. I need to set these formulas in the header row and columns AQ:1 to AV:1(AQ1:AV1).

```
["={"Hours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AF2:AF-AE2:AE)*24)+(((T2:T-S2:S)*24))+(((I2:I-H2:H)*24)),)))}",
"={"Rest Hours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((M2:M)*24)+(((X2:X)*24))+(((AJ2:AJ)*24)),)))}",
"={"Rest Hours Wages:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),(AI2:AI*(AJ2:AJ*24)+(L2:L*(M2:M*24)+(W2:W*(X2:X*24)))),)))}",
"={"Hours-RestHours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AQ2:AQ-AR2:AR)),)))}",
"={"Rate:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((E2:E+P2:P+AB2:AB)),)))}"],
```

and I need to put this into the second row of column AQ (AQ2).

```
["=ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AT2:AT*AU2:AU)+AS2:AS),)))}"],
```

I keep getting this error message and I cannot save the script.

> Missing ] after element list. (line 138, file "Code")

I think I know why but I need the headers to be titled with the correct text because I use the headers in other functions.

```
function setFormulas(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This sets the formulas to be a row of sums, followed by a row of averages right below.
// The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range.
var formulas = [
  ["={"Hours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AF2:AF-AE2:AE)*24)+(((T2:T-S2:S)*24))+(((I2:I-H2:H)*24)),)))}",
  "={"Rest Hours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((M2:M)*24)+(((X2:X)*24))+(((AJ2:AJ)*24)),)))}",
  "={"Rest Hours Wages:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),(AI2:AI*(AJ2:AJ*24)+(L2:L*(M2:M*24)+(W2:W*(X2:X*24)))),)))}",
  "={"Hours-RestHours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AQ2:AQ-AR2:AR)),)))}",
  "={"Rate:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((E2:E+P2:P+AB2:AB)),)))}",
  "={"Wages:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AT2:AT*AU2:AU)+AS2:AS),)))}"],
  ["=ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AT2:AT*AU2:AU)+AS2:AS),)))}"],
 ];

var cell = sheet.getRange("AQ1:AW2");
 cell.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

Am I missing something or am I doing it completely wrong and need to find another way to do it. I also need to add the formulas to every sheet in the spreadsheet but I have not been able to test if it works. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It's not correct to add a formula in the AQ2 because the formula in AQ1 is an array having 2 rows and 1 column, besides the formula in the second row could return an array of several rows.

Answer (score 2):

UPD:

It seems like double quotes are interfering here. To avoid this, you can use single quotes for formula enclosure and double quotes within formula, like this:

`'={"Hours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AF2:AF-AE2:AE)*24)+(((T2:T-S2:S)*24))+(((I2:I-H2:H)*24)),)))}'`

As mentioned in comments:

1. Arrays would expand so you are likely to need setting formulas in one row, like `AQ1:AW1`
2. Besides, if there's source data in columns AQ:AU (by the looks of formulas), setting array formulas in the same columns will most likely return error: `Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in AQ18`.
3. You seem to have an extra `}` at the end of the last formula

Try this and adjust to your needs:

```
function setFormulas(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This sets the formulas to be a row of sums, followed by a row of averages right below.
// The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range.
var formulas = [
  ['={"Hours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AF2:AF-AE2:AE)*24)+(((T2:T-S2:S)*24))+(((I2:I-H2:H)*24)),)))}',
  '={"Rest Hours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((M2:M)*24)+(((X2:X)*24))+(((AJ2:AJ)*24)),)))}',
  '={"Rest Hours Wages:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),(AI2:AI*(AJ2:AJ*24)+(L2:L*(M2:M*24)+(W2:W*(X2:X*24)))),)))}',
  '={"Hours-RestHours:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AQ2:AQ-AR2:AR)),)))}',
  '={"Rate:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((E2:E+P2:P+AB2:AB)),)))}',
  '={"Wages:";ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AT2:AT*AU2:AU)+AS2:AS),)))}',
  '=ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(AE2:AE),((AT2:AT*AU2:AU)+AS2:AS),)))']
 ];

var cell = sheet.getRange("AW1:BC1");
 cell.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it. I am almost certain it is the double quotes. However, the formula will not work without them in the spreadsheet. I will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Using the answers code in the OP's function returns `Incorrect range height, was 7 but should be 2 (line 18, file "Code")`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it, Ruben. I'll correct my reply now